# Ubuntu 16.04 Intel i7 4210HQ stuck at 800 MHz

Tags: 16.04, cpufreq

I have a HP laptop with i7-4210HQ (Quad core 2.5 - 3.2) and it started running choppy and slowly all of the sudden. I looked into it and the clock speed is sitting at 800 MHz at all times. I tried adjusting pstate (it defaults to powersave on reboot) to performance and it did not help. The pstate app even tells me that the pstate is set to performance and but the clock speed is still 800 MHz.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some more work, I ended up fixing the issue by disabling intel pstate in the grub loadup. Now the CPU is back up to speed.